# percentages in Openlayers css

Tags: css, openlayers, percentage

I am trying to adjust a map window to diferent computers and resolutions but I have some problems and I can't do it.

I have this in css right now:

```
#basicMap { 
      width: 828px; 
      height: 698px; 
      margin: 10px; 
      float: left; 
 } 
 html { 
      font-size: 10px; 
      bottom: 10px; 
      right: 10px; 
 }
```

In function ini():

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map ("basicMap", {
    controls:[.....]});
```

In my div:

```
 <div id="basicMap" ></div>
```

And it works fine but when I try to change 828px and 698px by 70% and 50% or other percentages, the map is not shown.

I have other divs in my webpage but I didn't specify their percentages or px yet.

Do I have to do anything else, or import another file?

Comment: Basically, `percentage` works when the element has a parent wrapper, i.e. `<div style="width:300px;height:300px"><div id="basicMap" ></div></div>` in this case if your `basicMap` has dimension in percentage then it'll be measured depending upon it's parent div's dimension.

Comment: So, should I add other div wrapping my basicMap div? And on the outer one, I have to use px to define its size... Is there a way to define the size of the webpage depending of resolution or screen size? I am trying to display it on 21", 15", 11.1"... smart phones...

Comment: Use [media query](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).